# How to set configuration in nested foreach loop container

Tags: ssis

The task is to load each sheet of multiple files (in the same folder)to the same sql server table, all the sheets have same formatting, can be loaded to the same sql table.

I am using visual studio data tool 2010. I know how to set looping file using Foreach File Enumerator in outer foreach loop container, and how to set looping sheet using Foreach ADO.NET Schema Rowset Enumerator in inner foreach loop container. My question is just how to make connection between these two foreach loop containers by passing the filepath dynamically.

I have tried to config the excel ado access connection manager-->property---> expression--->[name] to [fullfilepath] like  @[User::fileFolder]+ @[User::FileName], but doesn't work....

Anybody can help with this?? Thanks a lot!

[image: Connection Manager config[![foreach loop conf[![DFT config]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtT0a.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFGGQ.jpg)

Comment: Any error messages or insight why you decided that 'it does not work' would be beneficial.

Comment: my error shows as Error: The connection name "C:\ssis\Book1.xlsx" could not be found in the list of connections.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Matt for your insights. I finally got it through using ADO.NET for the inside looping for sheet. What I was missing before is lacking one extra excel connection manager for the DFT.

Answer (score 0):

From your error and description it appears the issue is you are setting the [name] property in the expression.  You should be setting the [connection string] property to the [fullfilepath] NOT the name property.

Concerning your Edits and Comments.
Interesting, I haven't tried exactly what you are wanting to do, but it seemed to me that you where using the wrong connection manger/provider type so I did a quick internet search to see if I could confirm and found this MS article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345182.aspx that looks to be almost exactly what you want.

The article shows the use of the Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider rather than the access provider you are attempting to use. I am not positive whether or not you can use the ACE OLEDB and get the same results or not you would have to try. However either way the connection string is not simply a file path like a flat file or excel connection manager would be instead it needs to be an appropriate connection string.

For Jet 4.0 which the access driver does use the article suggests:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +  @[User::fullfilepath] + ";Extended Properties=\"" + @[User::ExtProperties] + "\""
```

The back slashes in Extended properties are an escape sequence to include the double quotes.  The extended properties are required and relate to the version of Excel you are connecting to.

E.g. Excel 97 to 2003

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +  @[User::fullfilepath] + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
```

Excel 12.0 for 2007+

For the ACE driver it would be almost the same only change up the Provider Part.

E.g.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +  @[User::fullfilepath] + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment or the question from it.  I would suggest updating your question with a screen shot of your Expression configurations for the Excel Connection, and also discuss how/when you are setting the values of the variables you use there.  The issue from your comment concerning your error makes it seem like you are assigning the wrong values to the wrong properties.

Comment: have four variables: Folder-> C:\ssis\Book1.xlsx; filename->blank; fullfilepath->[User::folder]+"\\"+[User::filename];sheetname->blank  I changed to the  [connection string] to the fullfilepath, but didn't give me the looping through files, but just the first file repeated loaded to the sql server, and final an error [Connection manager "C:\ssis\Book1.xlsx"] Error: The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.

Comment: Hi Joan, It really is difficult to understand the problem without knowing more detail of how your package is configured.  Please update your post with the Control & Data Flow and when/how you are setting variable values and expression values.  Then we/the community may be able to better assist you.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have uploaded the config images. it gives me error for the connection string. I don't know where I set wrong and what is missing. Really appreciated!!!

Comment: see my updated answer for an article on what it looks like you are doing and a note about connection strings when using ADO.net connection manager